# SQL Server: when executing a query ; is there a way to get a list of the objects referenced (tables, view) in textual format?

Tags: sql-server

I'm aware of the query plan, but I'm looking for a list of objects that were referenced in textual format. I can deduce it from the query plan, but looking for a faster way.

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: There is no faster way, at least not from within T-SQL. The alternative is to parse the query with any of several available parsers (including [Microsoft's own](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser)) but from within T-SQL, the query plan is your best bet, especially considering T-SQL's poor support for string manipulation. Note that since there is support for processing XML, analyzing the query plan with T-SQL is quite doable (if not trivial).

Comment: If you are at liberty to create stored procedures in the database, there actually is an alternative: stick your query in an sproc, then use `sys.sql_dependencies` to retrieve the dependencies. (A view could also be used, but that only works for `SELECT` queries, of course.) Don't forget to remove the temporary object afterwards. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1a720171767c4db718e2566eff4ffec9).

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert : thanks for this info, the nice thing of course is that the queries are dynamically constructed and executed using sp_executesql so sys.sql_dependencies doesn't catch them :(. Thanks for your help, I know where I'm at :-)

Comment: Presumably when you mention the query plan, you're referring to the graphical view in SSMS? You can also retrieve the *planxml* as text using 'SET SHOWPLAN_XML' and also from SSMS (right click, *show Execution Plan XML*).

Comment: You can take the dynamic query, add `CREATE PROC TempProc` + any parameters + ` AS ` + your query, then use `sys.sql_dependencies` or `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities` to get the information you need. If you are not at liberty to create procedures in your database, you could create it in `tempdb` and add `USE YourDb;` at the top of the procedure. Don't forget to drop the procedure when you're done